# A, and hence A^3, is positive. Is or are?

Tags: word-choice

Here A is a number.

> A, and hence A^3, **is** positive
>
> A, and hence A^3, **are** positive.

which is right? I prefer the first.

Comment: A^ you mean pow(A, 3)?

Comment: Yes.  It is mathematical.

Answer (score 2):

You have the conjunction "and" connecting two items of equal weight. Therefore, you should use the plural.

> A, and hence A^3, **are** positive.

Comment: So, without the 'and', I should say, A, hence A^3, is positive?

Comment: I am not sure that your new sentence is correct in English. However, even without "and", you still have two things as the subject to one verb, so the plural is still recommended.